# Double pointer addresses

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

I created and allocated a double pointer like this:

```
 int **a;
 a = (int**)malloc(10 * sizeof(int *));
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     *(a+i) = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

And then I initialized it for example like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        **a = 1;
         (*a)++;
    }
    a++;
 }
```

My problem and question is how can I save the address'es of my double pointer?At this moment I lost them and can't use them anymore.

Comment: The original address is at `a-10`.

Comment: Don't mess with `a`. Just assign to it with `a[i][j] = ...`;

Comment: In C, do not cast the result of a call to `malloc()`, `realloc()`, or `calloc()` - it is unnecessary and potentially hides the serious error of a missing prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use explicit pointer arithmetic and dereferencing when array subscripting will do:

```
 int rows = 10, cols = 10
 int **a;
 // don't cast the return value of malloc
 a = malloc(rows * sizeof(*a));
 for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
     a[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(**a));

...

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        a[i][j] = 1;
    }
 }
```

Comment: That always make me sad when answer is about code practice but don't have good code practice like initialize value when possible or use the good type `size_t`, or even not allocate directly the type with sizeof but indirectly with the dereference type of the pointer, magic number too.

Comment: Thanks for respond and help but I already know that. I know that you can use easily a[i][j] and work with a[i][j] for the rest of the program and solve the problem.But I don't want to make the problem easier I want to solve it this way for me.The teacher told me already that but I want to deepen the knowledge of pointers.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu You should always favor code clarity over fancy trick unless you have a very specific performance related reason to do so.  That said, the equivalent to `a[i]` is `*(a + i)`, and by extension `a[i][j]` is the same as `*(*(a + i) + j)`.

Comment: @dbush I know that everything that you said until now and you're perfectly right but i tried for 1 hour to find out the answer to this "fancy trick"  by testing different things in my code.And the code i write up is just an example to point out my problem.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu The problem with your code is that you're changing `a` when you don't need to.  Either of the above indexing methods will work.

Comment: @dbush I understood that my code can be modified to be 10x easier like not using **a and a[i][j] , but let's say it's necessary to do it this way how do I do it then ?

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu If you insist on doing it as posted, then save a copy of `a`.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu If you want I made you a example, but I will not advice to use this unless for learning purpose : http://rextester.com/XLCPW7147, error handling omitted... `struct foo foo` => `struct foo const foo`

Comment: I tried to do that before posting this but It didn't work and i have no idea why.That's why I posted this.Edit: @Stargateur I see I just wanted to know for myself nothing more, thanks you both for help and good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Return a from a function, save it as a class member, it is just like any other variable. If you want to save the contents of the arrays then do that (but that is not what I could call saving a double pointer -- by the way the usual description is "pointer-to-pointer").